# Subletting Error in R, blank values are ignored

Tags: r, validation, dataframe

I have a huge df in which a column contains categories "Valid","In-Valid", and blank value. When I subset for NOT In-Valid (it should be Valid + Blank), I am getting only Valid and blank is missed out. here is a mock of data for which subsetting is working just fine. But for my actual data it is not working.

(NOT In-Valid should be Valid+Blank, but R is ignoring blank values)
R 3.3.2, none of the fields are factors,

```
a = LETTERS[1:10]
b = sample(c(T,F) , 10, T)
c = sample(c("Valid", "In-Valid", ""),10,T)
x = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
subset(x,x$c !="In-Valid") # here i get the valid answer but not to my actual df
```

Comment: Please check the `str(yourdataset)` and also check whether there are any `leading/lagging` spaces.  I think `subset(x, trimws(c) != "In-Valid")` can work

Comment: yea. the structure of column of interest is chr (not a factor). there is no whites pace to trim.

Comment: Then, check for NA elements.  In that case `subset(x, c != "In_Valid" & !is.na(c))`.  If you can show a small reproducible example that mimics the problem, it will be easier to solve.  Use `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))` assuming that it has the problem you mentioned